# Mail account used by django for password reset?

Tags: django, email

I am deploying my django project.
Having secured a domain name, i am now at the stage of Implementing a proper password reset mechanism on the deployed site.

I need to use an email service in order to do this, and having looked around, there seem to be many options for an email provider.

I could use mailgun, or gmail, or even the people who sold my domain offer a couple of email addresses along with it.

I was thinking i should maybe just go with gmail, as its free and forever, and probably pretty secure, probably reliable.

Can someone who knows about these matters, please advise me on what email provider i should use, or any issues i may have overlooked.

I glanced at mailgun, and it seems there is a limitation on amount of emails, so maybe that is a bad idea, i dont think gmail has a limitation. If so why do people use mailgun in the first place. Surely i must be missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main reason to go with a proper transactional email provider (transactional email = one-off emails for things like email verification, password reset, etc...) such as mailgun, postmark, sendgrid etc... is the fact that they do more than just SMTP. They can track what happens with your emails, report on bounces, opens, clicks etc... They also will do their best to ensure you don't get black-listed as spammer (although that's also your responsibility). Finally gmail is free but has limits: 500/day if I'm not mistaken. For a big platform with millions of users that can never scale.

Comment: none of the transactional email providers has limitations on the number of emails, but they all cost something beyond a certain threshold. Which is logical, they offer a very useful service and email delivery isn't free. Every free provider including your own hosting provider has limits, their purpose is delivery of private emails, not transactional emails.

Comment: Thanks so much dirkgroten, i get it now. So there is a difference and it seems quite important.

Comment: Look at [this article](https://zapier.com/learn/email-marketing/best-transactional-email-sending-services/) for some inspiration, which might help getting clarity on the requirements you have for your particular situation. I voted to close this question as you're asking recommendations on particular tools, which is off-topic on SO.

Comment: It's worth to mention that the free version of mailgun is a bad idea if you want to reach out to microsoft hosted emails (outlook.com, live.com, institutions which use outlook), since all of mailgun's sender ips are blocked in the microsoft network. There are plenty of complaints when you google for "mailgun outlook". The only solution by mailgun is to buy a dedicated ip for $ 50+ per month.

Comment: wow thanks for that critical piece of information